# Real part of a holomorphic function is bounded by polynomial then the holomorphic function is a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

Let $u$ be a harmonic function on $\mathbb{R}^2\cong \mathbb{C}$ such that $Ref= u$ where $f$ is an entire function. If $|u(z)|\leq |z|^n$ for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$, then $f$ is a polynomial of degree no greater than $n$.
How to prove this? I am quite confused. Thanks.

Comment: I found this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262355/polynomial-bounded-real-part-of-an-entire-function?rq=1

Comment: You can also argue with the Poisson integral, like [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433306/why-is-this-function-constant).